# Display date as MONTH YEAR format from Mysql using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, datetime, formatting

**This is the query**
datemade is date datatype in MYSQL

```
     $sqlCommand ="SELECT blogbody,datemade FROM blogpages WHERE bpid='$blogid'";
```

**This is the fetch array**

```
        $dmade=$row["datemade"];
```

**I echo out the date** how can we display it as ex: **November 2014**

Comment: have you tried anything? any attempts to format?

Comment: No,but i dont know where to format it.my date shows as  2014-09-15

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [DATE_FORMAT function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) with `'%M %Y'` as the format parameter to display month name and four digit year like below

```
DATE_FORMAT(datemade, '%M %Y')
```

This is the modified query

```
$sqlCommand = "SELECT blogbody, DATE_FORMAT(datemade, '%M %Y') AS datemade FROM blogpages WHERE bpid='$blogid'";
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use MySQL [DATE_FORMAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) function.

Change your query to:

```
$sqlCommand ="SELECT blogbody, DATE_FORMAT(datemade, '%M %Y') AS datemade FROM blogpages WHERE bpid='$blogid'";
```